# NextJS, load and render a Markdown file

Tags: webpack, next.js

I've been trying to set up my webpack config file to load .md files but had no success. I've tried the `markdown-loader`, the `remark-loader` but both of these unsuccesfully. Not sure how to add them to my existing config,

```
// This uses phases as outlined here: https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-configuration
module.exports = (phase) => {
    const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER;
    const isProd = phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD && process.env.STAGING !== "1";
    const isStaging = phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD && process.env.STAGING === "1";
    const env = {
        MONGODB_URI: (() => {
            return process.env.MONGODB_URI;
        })(),
    };

    // next.config.js object
    return {
        env,
        swcMinify: false,
    };
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "load .md files"? Is it loaded when calling a dynamic page url? Or is it static site rendering?

Comment: @PsyGik I have a .md file locally that I'd like to render on the page. Nothing else, no dynamic urls, just a static page

Comment: May I suggest using mdx-bundler, which is build for that specific use-case. https://github.com/kentcdodds/mdx-bundler#usage

Comment: @PsyGik can I ask for a small snippet as an answer to accept it? It seems really simple to use but they provide no examples. I am trying to use it with Nextjs, to load "example.md" into ExamplePage, if its not too much to ask to write a snippet for this kind of setup? I don't really understand where the loading happens

Comment: Here is an example repo: https://github.com/pyadav/use-mdx-bundler-with-next-js